# Weird fatal crash with ExifInterface and VM aborting

Tags: android, exif

I'm getting a strange fatal crash with ExifInterface. The line that gives the crash is this, quite straightforward (Foto.java:341):

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filename);
```

I only get the crash with some pictures. Even more strange is the fact that if I see a normal picture's exif, close the program, and open the program again to see a problematic picture, I get the exif from the previous image. Quite strage.

Any idea what is causing this? The Strack Trace is below.

```
01-13 21:23:42.148: W/dalvikvm(10868): JNI WARNING: received null jstring
01-13 21:23:42.148: W/dalvikvm(10868):              in Landroid/media/ExifInterface;.getAttributesNative:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; (GetStringUTFChars)
01-13 21:23:42.148: I/dalvikvm(10868): "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
01-13 21:23:42.148: I/dalvikvm(10868):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40c6e460 self=0x12938
01-13 21:23:42.148: I/dalvikvm(10868):   | sysTid=10868 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1075021096
01-13 21:23:42.148: I/dalvikvm(10868):   | schedstat=( 618641072 82163138 362 ) utm=57 stm=4 core=1
01-13 21:23:42.148: I/dalvikvm(10868):   at android.media.ExifInterface.getAttributesNative(Native Method)
01-13 21:23:42.148: I/dalvikvm(10868):   at android.media.ExifInterface.loadAttributes(ExifInterface.java:204)
01-13 21:23:42.148: I/dalvikvm(10868):   at android.media.ExifInterface.<init>(ExifInterface.java:121)
01-13 21:23:42.148: I/dalvikvm(10868):   at com.floritfoto.apps.xvf.Foto.printexif(Foto.java:341)
01-13 21:23:42.148: I/dalvikvm(10868):   at com.floritfoto.apps.xvf.Foto$3.onLongClick(Foto.java:449)
01-13 21:23:42.148: I/dalvikvm(10868):   at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:3656)
01-13 21:23:42.148: I/dalvikvm(10868):   at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:14270)
01-13 21:23:42.148: I/dalvikvm(10868):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-13 21:23:42.148: I/dalvikvm(10868):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-13 21:23:42.148: I/dalvikvm(10868):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-13 21:23:42.148: I/dalvikvm(10868):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
01-13 21:23:42.148: I/dalvikvm(10868):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 21:23:42.148: I/dalvikvm(10868):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-13 21:23:42.148: I/dalvikvm(10868):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
01-13 21:23:42.148: I/dalvikvm(10868):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
01-13 21:23:42.148: I/dalvikvm(10868):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-13 21:23:42.148: E/dalvikvm(10868): VM aborting
01-13 21:23:42.148: A/libc(10868): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1)
```

Comment: It seems that this is related to CheckJNI = ON?

Answer (score 0):

new ExifInterface(null) will cause SIGSEGV.

Same answer here: [Android Bitmap Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221136/android-bitmap-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv)